# Git: strip changes from unrelated repository after fetch or how to fix "warning: no common commits"?

Tags: git

I use

```
$ git remote show origin 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git://gitorious.org/bash/bash.git
```

but there no any new changes since 2011. So I google where is official sources: http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash

I decide to make new origin:

```
$ git remote rename origin gitorious
$ git remote add origin git://git.savannah.gnu.org/bash.git
```

and `fetch` latest changes in order to compare that happen (`git log master..origin/master`):

```
$ git fetch origin 
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 23368, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3449/3449), done.
^Cceiving objects:   8% (1895/23368), 8.51 MiB | 478.00 KiB/s
```

After I see `warning: no common commits` I break fetching and wander how to strip this unrelated fetched changes from local repository (I know that I need clean `clone`).

I am better with `hg` and it always complain about unrelated repositories unless you `-f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to completely discard the previous remote, you can simply delete it:

```
git remote remove <remote-name>
```

What this does, though, is only to remove the remote entry and the remote-tracking branch labels.  Let me show a (very) simplified example of two remotes with two unrelated commit DAGs, plus your own local changes.  Let's call the two remotes `rmt1` and `rmt2` (one might actually be `gitorious` now and the other `origin` but I want to generalize a bit):

```
           L     <-- master
         /
A0 <- A1 <- A2     <-- rmt1/master

B0 <- B1 <- B2 <- B3   <-- rmt2/master
```

The `A` commits represent everything you brought over from remote `rmt1` (the remote you had initially, probably `gitorious` now).  Here you *also* have one local commit `L` with some change you made to the stuff you got from `rmt1`, and you've just added remote `rmt2` and brought over its commit graph (the `B` commits).

If you now run `git remote remove rmt1`, git deletes the configuration line, and also the `rmt1/master` label.  Here's what you are left with, not counting commits that have gone invisible but have not been garbage-collected:

```
           L     <-- master
         /
A0 <- A1

B0 <- B1 <- B2 <- B3   <-- rmt2/master
```

The problem here is that your own local changes (commit `L`) use, and therefore preserve, at least some of the original commit graph—the `A`-series commits.

Presumably, what you want to do is find some or all of your local commits that are *not* `rmt1` commits, see what changes you've made that you want to keep, and find some suitable commit(s) to base those changes on in the `B`-series commits.  If there's only one local commit, as in this case, that's pretty easy; but if there are many, you must decide which one(s) you want to preserve.

In many cases, you have one or two branches you actively use now, and the tip of those branches are what you want to keep.  In this kind of case you might simply save away your old git repository, make a whole new git repository by cloning the `B` series (in this case from `git.savannah.gnu.org`), and pick some branch(es) in the new repo onto which you'll port your active branch-tips.  Here you'd just use your saved repository to extract patches (git diff or git format-patch, for instance) and then import those to the new repository.  This is a lot simpler conceptually.

In other cases, though, you might really want to keep both remote repos' contents in one repo, at least for some time until you can rebase or otherwise preserve your changes.  This is a convenient way to keep and copy both sets of DAGs, and it lets you use git commands on commits in either (independent) graph, including diff-ing a tree in one graph vs a tree in another.  It's conceptually more complex, and is the direction you're going at the moment.

I can't really recommend one approach or the other without knowing much more about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning. There will be two unrelated commit trees (and e.g. `gitk` visualizes them as unrelated, one by one), but other than that there will be no  other differences, all git commands (`diff`, `merge`, `cherry-pick` etc) continue to work as expected.

To clear/hide unneeded revisions, you may simply remove references to them, and this is the common rule for entire git. In the case of the second remote repository this means you need to remove appropriate `remote`: `git remote rm origin`. You also can remove references manually in `.git/refs/remotes/<remote-name>` and `.git/packed-refs`.

Once references are removed, the corresponding objects in the repository will be eventually deleted and space reclaimed. you also can run `git gc` manually.

Comment: Ok, how can I clean/strip/remove unrelated changes? I don't expect that repositories unrelated and don't want to bother with unrelated commits...